# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'NoneType' for statsmodels SimpleExpoentialSmoothing

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, holtwinters

I am trying to create a simple exponential smoothing model by following this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-in-python-exponential-smoothing-and-arima-processes-2c67f2a52788

but have run into problems I do not understand. I have a very simple pandas DataFrame called `time_series` with daily datetime index and a value between 20 and 100 for number of people attending a clinic for that day. It looks as such:

```
            patients
Date                
2015-01-04        49
2015-01-05        51
2015-01-06        48
2015-01-07        30
2015-01-08        27
```

However I receive an error when running line `fit1` in the following code which I created to build to SES model. The code to build is as follows:

```
train, test = train_test_split(time_series, test_size=0.30, shuffle=False)

model = SimpleExpSmoothing(np.asarray(train['patients']))
model._index = pd.to_datetime(train.index)

fit1 = model.fit()
pred1 = fit1.forecast(9)
fit2 = model.fit(smoothing_level=.2)
pred2 = fit2.forecast(9)
fit3 = model.fit(smoothing_level=.5)
pred3 = fit3.forecast(9)
```

The error is the following which I find strange as I have checked and both train and test contain no null values:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'NoneType'
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Could you add code of the function `train_test_split` in the edit 1?

Comment: Maybe the amount of data is too low, try with a larger dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way. It worked for me:

```py
train.index = pd.to_datetime(train.index)
model = SimpleExpSmoothing(np.asarray(train['patients']))
```